# Variables in URL won't work when not testing locally

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I've been working on a project on my local server. The time has come to upload it so I did just that. I started to test it out online and my navigation isn't working.

The navigation works by doing this:

```
<a href="index.php?p=add">Add</a>
```

The page then checks whether `$p` exists and if it does, it shows the relevant content. For some reason though my content isn't showing up when I click the links. I turned on error reporting, and I added this (line 39)

```
echo $p;
```

to the document. Now I get this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: p in /home/silver/public_html/admin/index.php on line 39` but only when testing online and it works fine when I test it locally.

I can post my code if I need to, but there's a lot of it and I'm not sure which bit is the problem.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for all the replies, but I'm confused as to how you use your suggestions as I'm used to doing things the way I was.

At the moment, I do this to check what the `$p` variable is

```
<?php if(!isset($p)) { // DEFAULT PAGE VIEWED AT INDEX.PHP ?>
```

And use this to link to the page:

```
<a href="index.php?p=add">Add New Item</a>
```

Comment: Do you have something which says `$p = $_GET['p'];`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're relying upon [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php), an outdated and deprecated feature of PHP.  This feature automatically translates GET, POST, COOKIE, SERVER etc. variables and inserts them into the global scope.  This means that `file.php?p=blah` would result in `$p == 'blah'`.  This is a bad idea for lots of different scoping and security reasons outlined [in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Use the [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) (e.g. `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SERVER`) instead.

---

In response to your updated question, your code

```
<?php if(!isset($p)) { // DEFAULT PAGE VIEWED AT INDEX.PHP ?>
```

should become

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['p'])) { // DEFAULT PAGE VIEWED AT INDEX.PHP ?>
```

Comment: Magic quotes is a different feature, but should not be used either.

Comment: Will I need to do similar things with things like this? `<li<?php if($c=="crushers") echo " class=\"current\""; ?>>Basic Crushers / Crushers</li>`. For example will `$c==` need to become `$_GET['c']==`?

Comment: @Chrish If `$c` is coming from the URL, yes. You could import it as `$c = $_GET['c'];`

Answer (score 1):

`$p` doesn't automatically get set from the parameter in the URL. You need to attach `$p` to the value coming from the URL by using the code `$p = $_GET['p'];` first.

Be weary though, you need to sanitize this `GET` parameter and/or create a whitelist to make sure it is a valid parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on an old and very bad "feature" of PHP called [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.register-globals) that loads variables directly from GET. You need to do `$p = $_GET['p']` if you want `$p` to be set via an HTTP GET.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because 'register_globals' is ON on your dev system and OFF on your live system. Set it to OFF on your dev and use $_GET['p']